# Meteor keypress event not working

Tags: forms, events, meteor

I'm aiming to capture the form input and log that in the console. I've tried several variations of the following code and I always end up with the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

I've created an example on meteorpad: http://meteorpad.com/pad/9uqj8EDH3j5epKb3f/Line

What might be the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was the event was listening on the form and not the input. Here's a working solution:

```js
'keyup .line': function(event) {
  var line = $(event.currentTarget).val();
  console.log(line);
}
```